# What is use of backdrop property and keyboard property of model window in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is use of backdrop property and keyboard property of model window in angular js

Comment: I think it has not to do with AngularJs, but with Bootstrap.

Comment: In model window of angularjs there are also same property                       1 )backdrop property and                                                                                         2) keyboard property.

Answer (score 0):

There are main two property backdrop and keyboard in every model window.

**Backdrop property** In you can set two property backdrop = 'static' Clicking outside of model window,model window will not get closed with background will be grayed out.
backdrop = 'false' Clicking outside of model window,model window will not get closed but background will not be grayed out. backdrop = 'true' Clicking outside window, model window will get closed.

**keyboard property** keyboard = 'false' By pressing esc key model window will not get closed.
keyboard = 'true' By pressing esc key model window will get closed.